# MySQL AND not working as expected

Tags: mysql, where-clause

First of all, here is the query I am trying to use.

```
SELECT * FROM Messages t WHERE perspective_user=? and timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND 
timestamp_added = 
(select max(timestamp_added) from Messages t2 
where 
t2.author = t.author AND
t2.body = t.body AND
t2.timestamp = t.timestamp AND
t2.timestamp_added <= ?
) AND convo_id IN (SELECT convo_id FROM Conversations WHERE perspective_user=? AND identity=? AND timestamp_added=?);
```

The code works fine without the following line, but with it, it returns 0 results.

```
AND convo_id IN (SELECT convo_id FROM Conversations WHERE perspective_user=? AND identity=? AND timestamp_added=?);
```

I've also verified that the above line works on its own, tested on a basic SELECT * query. I've also made sure that there are rows in the database that satisfy the top query.

The data is a log of Skype messages. Logs are taken randomly; the goal is to get the most recent log that is still in the database. The goal is to be able to graph my Skype messages and do other fun things. Skype purges its database on my computer of older messages. The long "timestamp_added" statement is to get the newest of each message, so that if the latest log had a purged database, old messages would still be included.

Comment: Some sample data?

Comment: You really are going to have to provide sample data and bind parameters and expected output.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using the t2 subselect?

Comment: is the Conversations timestamp_added check maybe supposed to be `<=`, not `=`?

Comment: Try putting parentheses around all the separate AND statements.

Answer (score -1):

First thing, that I see is that you have a space between IN and parenthesis — MySQL "hates" it. Fix it like that:

```
...AND convo_id IN(SELECT...
```

But if it's just topic posting typo error, then please share your data (MySQL scheme of `Messages` and `Conversations`).

Comment: This very well could be the problem. Why is that?

Comment: Did you tested?
I'm not sure why, but I've often faced this problem before in my practice. Looks like in [official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) space after IN is acceptable.

Comment: Oh, it's skype db file :) I suppose that it's not MySQL, Skype uses SQLite. And I'm not sure do SQLite "IN" works same as MySQL "IN".

Comment: I'm pulling it out of the SQLite database and putting it in MySQL. This query is pulling out of the MySQL database. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm still figuring out what indexes to add. Right now, I have trouble testing because it usually times out.

Comment: The space is not a problem

Comment: @Stephen, 1) please forget about your query and just explain what you want to do? 2) is your mysql table structure (table names, fields names, fields types etc.) same as original skype .db files?

Answer (score -1):

The statement below return a list of rows where as what you need to pass to an IN() function is a CSV.

```
(SELECT convo_id FROM Conversations WHERE perspective_user=? AND identity=? AND timestamp_added=?)
```

So instead use GROUP_CONCAT() like this

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(convo_id) FROM Conversations WHERE perspective_user=? AND identity=? AND timestamp_added=? GROUP BY convo_id)
```

Comment: Um, no.  The subselect used by IN should return rows with a single value in each, not a comma separated string.

Comment: @ysth: you are right. I just looked at the documentaion for IN() so the misunderstanding. http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php